# superclass in ruby class is 'Object' but for 'Class' is 'Module

Tags: ruby

In Metaprogramming Ruby book, I can across the concept of superclass and class.
Here is the reference image:

[image: Object class superclass explained]

As I understand: *Class* has an instance method defined *superclass* , which can be called by any new class defined (Here *MyClass*)

My question is:

The parent *Class* has superclass as *Module* but the object *MyClass* has superclass as *Object* . Why does superclass of *Myclass* is *Object* but not *Module* ? If it is by design, why is it designed this way?

Answer (score 2):

If you define a new class `Foo` in Ruby, then indeed, it is an instance of `Class` class, and `Foo.class.superclass` is `Module` as expected. But since you are asking not about the ancestors of `Foo.class`, but directly about the ancestors of `Foo`, then know that

```
class Foo
end
```

is the same as writing

```
class Foo < Object
end
```

In other words, a newly defined class will by default become a subclass of `Object` class, unless otherwise specified. Of course, you could manually define

```
class Bar < Module
end
```

in order to create an explicit subclass of `Module` class. Descendants of `Module` class have specific qualities and are of special use in Ruby. Note that class `Class` cannot be subclassed.